# Limits of a map on the space of bounded sequences

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

I'm working on an exercise consisting of several questions that I can't quite figure out. If someone could give me any tips I'd be very happy!

For $\xi = (x_1, x_2,...) \in \ell^\infty$ define
\begin{align*}
a_n(\xi) = \sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} x_{i + j}.
\end{align*}

The first question was to prove that for any $\xi = (x_1, x_2, ...) \in \ell^\infty$ and $n,m,i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > m$
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} x_{i + j} \leq (1 - \frac{r}{n}) a_m (\xi) + \frac{m}{n} \| \xi \|_\infty,
\end{align*}
when $n = km + r$ with $0 \leq r < m$ and $k,r \in \mathbb{N}_0$.

The second question is to conclude, using the first question that 
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n( \xi) \leq a_m (\xi)
\end{align*}
for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\xi \in \ell^\infty$.

The final question is to use the second question to prove that $\lim_{m \to \infty} a_m(\xi)$ exists for all $\xi \in \ell^\infty$.

What I have done so far:

Proving the first question isn't that difficult I think:

We can split $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j = 0}^{n-1} x_{i + j}$ into
\begin{align*}
\frac{x_{i} + x_{i +1} + ... + x_{i + km}}{n} + \frac{x_{i + km + 1} + ... + x_{i + n - 1}}{n},
\end{align*}
where the first sum is $km$ terms long, and the second sum is $r$ terms long.

Rewriting $(1 - \frac{1}{n}) a_m (\xi) + \frac{m}{n} \| \xi \|_\infty$ gives
\begin{align*}
(1 - \frac{1}{n}) a_m (\xi) + \frac{m}{n} \| \xi \|_\infty &= \frac{n - r}{n} \sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{m} \sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1} x_{i + j} + \frac{m}{n} \| \xi \|_\infty \\
&= k \frac{ \sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} x_{i+j}}{n} +  m\frac{\| \xi \|_\infty}{n}.
\end{align*}
Compare this with the first sum and make two inequalities and you're mostly done.

I'm kind of stumped on the second and third question though...

We see that
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n (\xi) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{k \geq n, i \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j = 0}^{k - 1} x_{i + j}.
\end{align*}

Now, I'd like to write
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{k \geq n, i \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j = 0}^{k - 1} x_{i + j} &\leq \lim_{n \to \infty}\sup_{k \geq n, i \in \mathbb{N}}  (1 - \frac{r}{n}) a_m (\xi) + \frac{m}{n} \| \xi \|_\infty \\
&=  \lim_{n \to \infty}  (1 - \frac{r}{n}) a_m (\xi) + \frac{m}{n} \| \xi \|_\infty \\
&= a_m(\xi).
\end{align*}

but I just don't see this holding for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$: we have $n = km + r$, so taking the limit $n \to \infty$, shouldn't $m$ increase as well?

Moving on then, I have no idea how to show that if the $\limsup$ exists, the $\lim$ exists as well. Should I calculate $\liminf$ to show that $\limsup = \liminf$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second question, fix $m$. Then you have for every $n$ from the first question
$$
a_n(\xi)\leq (1-\frac{1}{n})a_m(\xi) + \frac{m}{n}||\xi||_\infty.
$$
From this you conlude that $\limsup_n a_n(\xi)$ exists and it must be less or equal of the $\lim_n$ of the right side of the inequality. This answers the second question.

The third question is answered similarly, you were on the right track with the $\liminf$. Do you get it?

Comment: What I don't get is that when fixing $m$, the inequality still holds for every $n$... $n$ is based on $n = km + r$, and I've only proven it for that situation, so how can it hold for every $n$ ?

Comment: Sorry, of course $k$ can be increased, while $r < m$ can be used to offset any differences.. Then since $a_n(\xi)$ is always bounded, the $\limsup$ exists. The rest follows from that.

Comment: And I've figured the third question out as well using $-\liminf a_n(\xi) = \limsup -a_n(\xi) \leq -a_m(\xi)$. Thanks for the help!